# ArduinoのfloatつまりIEEE 754表現の，1byteずつに着目したいです

Tags: c++, c, arduino

こんにちは，
今回はArduinoのfloat, つまりIEEE 754表現について教えていただきたいです．

floatは4byteで構成されていますが，その1byteずつを数字で表すとどうなるのでしょうか？２進数でも，10進数でも，16進数でも構いません.

たとえば，pi=3.141592というfloatは，1byteずつ数字で表すとどうなりますでしょうか？

いただいた回答は，私の手持ちのプログラムによって，

```
data[0]=上位1byte 
data[1]=次の1byte 
data[2]=次の次の1byte 
data[3]=下位1byte
```

として格納し，以下のようなbitシフトを使って元の値に戻るか確かめます．(もしbitシフトの方法も間違えているようであれば教えてくださいませ）

```
float re_pi = (float) (
      (((uint32_t)data[0] << 24) & 0xFF000000)
    | (((uint32_t)data[1] << 16) & 0x00FF0000)
    | (((uint32_t)data[2] <<  8) & 0x0000FF00)
    | (((uint32_t)data[3] <<  0) & 0x000000FF)
);
```

9/20追記　SPIに使っているコードを追記します．

```
#include <SPI.h>

volatile uint32_t data[4];
volatile uint8_t count=0;



  
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    SPCR |= _BV(SPE);
    SPI.attachInterrupt();  // (3)
}

void loop(){
    
   
}



ISR(SPI_STC_vect){  // (4)
  
  data[count]=SPDR;
  count += 1;
  
  if(count==4){
    count=0;
   
   
    float result = (float) (
          (((uint32_t)data[0] << 24) & 0xFF000000)
        | (((uint32_t)data[1] << 16) & 0x00FF0000)
        | (((uint32_t)data[2] <<  8) & 0x0000FF00)
        | (((uint32_t)data[3] <<  0) & 0x000000FF)
    );
    
    Serial.println(result);
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こういうのは自分の手でいろいろ試してみるのが吉。
[浮動小数点数内部表現シミュレータ](https://tools.m-bsys.com/calculators/ieee754.php)
これによると `3.141592` は `0x40490FD8` だそうな。

んで、後者の代入なんですが文法的には正しいのですが `0x40490FD8` という整数（１０進数表記すると `1078530008`） を `float` に代入するという意味に解釈されるので期待した動作にはならないでしょう。なのでここは別途の工夫が必要です。今のこの時点では宿題にしておこう。

通信で送る受けるの際にはたいていバイト列として送るとよいのですが、先の値を

- 0x40 0x49 0x0F 0xD8 の順に送るか
- 0xD8 0x0F 0x49 0x40 の順に送るか

は送る側と受ける側での事前の合意が必要です（ネットワーク電文の設計っスね）
そして(先の変換の話に絡んでくるので)こういうときは[エンディアネス](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3)という話が必ず出てきます。 Arduino がどっち raspberrypi がどっちかは練習なので自分で調べてみましょう。

---

SPI 通信って１つのトランザクション内でコマンドとデータが不可分なので、コメントにある通り受信側はたいてい「コマンドとデータが１つにまとまった値」を (32bit なり 16bit なりで) 受け取ることになります。今欲しいのはそのうちのデータペイロード 8bit 分だけのはず。よって受信側はデータ部だけを抽出するコードが必要です。

```
// コンパイルとか一切してない手書きプログラムっス
uint32_t data[4]; // SPI 受信結果の生データ（コマンドを含むもの）
union my_receive_data_converter_type {
    uint8_t bytes[4]; // SPI 受信１回に含まれるペイロードバイト
    float value; // SPI 受信４回で成立する float の値
};
my_recive_data_coverter_type f;
// ペイロードバイトが 32bit 値の下位 8bit に入っているとして
for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) { f.bytes[i]=(uint8_t)(data[i]&0xFF); }
DebugPrint(f.value);
```

こんな感じ。このコードを実行するタイミングがいつであるとかはあえて省略しますので考えてみてください。

このサンプル自体はエンディアンについては意識していません。どこをどう修正すると「バス上観測されるであろう信号のエンディアン」「メモリに格納する際のエンディアン」が変わるかも宿題にしときます。

# SPI の場合 32bit Transaction で 16bit Payload が運べそうな気がする。

Comment: ありがとうございます！エンディアンについて調べてきました．データを格納する順番とのこと，そしてArduinoはリトルエンディアンで，小さい順格納されるとのことはわかりました．なので0x40490FD8 は普段，逆順でArduinoに入っていることがわかり，通信では0x40 0x49 0x0F 0xD8 の順に送ればいいことになります（
実はspi通信でRaspiからpi=0x40490FD8を1バイトずつ送っていて，それを Arduinoではuint32_t dataに格納しています）

少しメタ的な話をしますと，リトルエンディアンかビッグエンディアンしかないのですから．２通り試せばどちらかは動くはずです．
なので，今の問題は，受け取った後のdataの代入の段階と分かりました．

実際，dataの中身は[ 64, 73, 15 ,216]のようなものですが，どうやらbitシフトではうまくいかないようですね…(
整数のシフトと勘違いされる）

どうすれば良いでしょうか

Comment: コードいただきありがとうございます．構造体の定義を先にして，データが四つ揃った後に処理の文を書けば，うまくいきました！ありがとうございます．脳内で書いただけなのに，すごいです．


少し，追加で聞かせてください．「コマンドと不可分」という意味が分かりかねています．ここでいうコマンドとはなんでしょうか？例えば，最初の構造体定義では，uint8_t byte[4]は，1byteの数を4個格納する箱ですよね．ここで受け取るのはつまりは0-255の値です．てっきり，SPIから受け取った情報は1byteの数の情報だけかと思っていました(attachInterrupt で割り込みが入るたびに data[i]=SPDR;追記より ）
SPIは0-255以外の情報も渡してきているということでしょうか？

Comment: また,unionはいくつかの記事で「好ましくない結果を引き起こすからmemcpyを代わりに使うように」とあるのですが，どのようにお考えですか？

Comment: SPI の挙動についてはよい質問なので別途挙げていただくと幸い。 `union` が好ましくないのはまさにこのエンディアンが異なる場合などに書き直さなきゃならない点なので、この例のように使う機器が既に決まっていて、ソフトを他の機種に移植する必要がないのなら気にしなくてOK。

Answer (score 0):

`float re_pi = *((float*)data);` ででてくるんじゃないかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます．色々試しましたが，0.00になってしまいます．詳しく書きます．実は，pi通信でRaspiからpi=0x40490FD8を1バイトずつ受け取っていて，それを uint32_t dataに格納してから変換しています．(なのでdataの中身は，[ 64, 73, 15 ,216]となっています）

Comment: この処理のどこかで良くないことをしていますか？

Comment: 訂正：spi通信，誤：pi通信

Comment: arduinoがどうなのかは知りませんが、`float *`へのキャストだと一般的にはアライメントの問題が出てきます。

Comment: 理解が足りなければすみません．Arduino側ではエラーが出ることはなく，0.00とシリアルプリントされるだけになります．何か原因は考えられますでしょうか

Comment: 質問文に書かれてないことを後付でいわれてもどうしようもないです。

それなら、その0x40490FD8をIEEE754表現でどういう値になるか調べてみては。
これが3.14... になるのかならないのかですよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます．そうします！助かりました